adding \usepackage{subcaption} makes tex4ht not correctly align caption below image in graphics
This MWE
\documentclass[12pt]{book}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}    
\newcommand{\addImage}[4]
{
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{framed}
\includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#3}\caption{#4}
\end{framed}
\end{figure}
}%
\usepackage{subcaption}    
\begin{document}    
\addImage{1}{0.3}{example-image-a}{Phase line diagram}    
\end{document}

Compiled with lualatex, gives correct output, with caption below the image

But compiled with tex4ht using the command
make4ht -ulm default -a debug A.tex 'mathjax,htm'

gives this

Removing \usepackage{subcaption} from the code, now tex4ht gives correct output

Is there a workaround for tex4ht?
TL 2024, updated 3 days ago.
Reference 641 tracking

This seems to be caused by a recent change that I've done to caption.4ht, which was done to fix a support for the Svjour3 class. Here is the fixed version:
% caption.4ht (2024-10-18-14:47), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2007-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2024 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <https://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2024-10-18-14:47}

\let\sv:toclof\toclof
\def\toclof#1#2#3{%
   \bgroup
     \def\a:TocLink##1##2##3##4{\gdef\:temp{##4}}%
     #2%
   \egroup
   \ifx \:temp\empty \else
      \sv:toclof{#1}{#2}{#3}%
   \fi
}
\let\lof:ConfigureToc\ConfigureToc
\long\def\ConfigureToc#1#2#3#4#5{%
   \lof:ConfigureToc{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
   \def\:temp{#1}\def\:tempa{lof}\ifx \:temp\:tempa
      \let\toc:lof\toclof
      \def\toclof##1##2##3{%
         \bgroup
           \def\a:TocLink####1####2####3####4{\gdef\:temp{####4}}%
           ##2%
         \egroup
         \ifx\:temp\empty\else
            \toc:lof {##1}{##2}{##3}%
         \fi
   }\fi%
}

\ifdefined\cptA:\else
\c:def\cptA:{}\c:def\cptB:{}%
\c:def\cptC:{}\c:def\cptD:{}
\fi 

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \xdef\continuedfloat@captype{\@captype}%
  \caption@make@above%
  \cptA:\caption@@make{\cap:ref{#1}}{\cptC:#2}\cptD:%
  \caption@make@below%
}
\long\def\caption@makecaption#1#2{%
  \xdef\continuedfloat@captype{\@captype}%
  \caption@make@above%
  \cptA:\caption@@make{\cap:ref{#1}}{\cptC:#2}\cptD:%
  \caption@make@below%
}

 \renewcommand*\caption@@@addcontentsline[4]{%
   \def\temp{#1}\def\tempa{toc}\ifx \temp\tempa\else%
   \gHAdvance\TitleCount  1%
   \fi%
   \addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{\protect\numberline{#3}{\detokenize{#4}}}%
 }


\Hinput{caption}
\endinput

The change I had to done, is to check if the macros that caused issues with Svjour3 are undefined. If they are, we need to define, otherwise we should leave them:
\ifdefined\cptA:\else
\c:def\cptA:{}\c:def\cptB:{}%
\c:def\cptC:{}\c:def\cptD:{}
\fi 

This is the result:

